# Is there another way to set spring.data.rest.base-path than properties which are ignored?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have this in my `application.yml`

spring:
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: /api

But it keep getting ignored by my configuration and it start the repository in `/`

Is there any way to configure it in java code or differently ?

I have found this but it's a bit deprecated :

http://pavelmakhov.com/2016/02/spring-data-rest-change-base-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Configuration
class CustomRestMvcConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {

    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        configuration.setBasePath("/api")
      }
    };
  }
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri